# MySQL + JAVA - Can't insert a table into another

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I can't seem to insert my old table into the new table. Very weird

Code:

```
INSERT INTO 'newhawk_playewadwds' (`player_id`,'player') SELECT `player_id`,'player' FROM 'hawk_playewadwds';
```

Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You
have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQ
L server version for the right syntax to use near ''newhawk_playewadwds' (`playe
r_id`,'player') SELECT `player_id`,'player' FROM 'h' at line 1
```

Extra info:

Both tables exist and have slightly diffrent column structors (One has a varchar(50), while the other doesn't). Which is why i included the direct columns in the statement.

Comment: Which has varchar of 50?

Comment: You are using single quotes where you should be using backticks.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close these questions.

Answer (score 5):

Quotes are delimiters for strings. Use backticks to escape column and table names, not quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `newhawk_playewadwds` (`player_id`,`player`) 
SELECT `player_id`,`player` 
FROM `hawk_playewadwds`;
```

But you actually only need to escape the [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Not sure how i managed to replace `, with ', but i did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `'` char with table names and for column `player` as below

```
INSERT INTO `newhawk_playewadwds` (`player_id`,`player`) 
SELECT `player_id`,`player` 
FROM `hawk_playewadwds`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks across the query. You are using backticks and single quotes. Either use backticks or remove the single quotes:

```
-- This will work (Backticks only)
INSERT INTO `newhawk_playewadwds` (`player_id`,`player`) 
SELECT `player_id`,`player` 
FROM `hawk_playewadwds`;

-- This will also work (No backticks and no single quotes)
INSERT INTO newhawk_playewadwds (player_id,player) 
SELECT player_id,player 
FROM hawk_playewadwds;
```

Another thing, as you mentioned column structures are different,

1. If `newhawk_playewadwds` has column > 50, and `hawk_playewadwds` has < 50, It shouldn't be a problem
2. If `hawk_playewadwds' has > 50 and`newhawk_playewadwds` has <50, then do either of the following:

   1. Increase the size of the new table `newhawk_playewadwds` to same size of `hawk_playewadwds`
   2. Use Substring in select as:

      ```
      INSERT INTO `newhawk_playewadwds` (`player_id`,`player`) 
          SELECT `player_id`,SUBSTRING(`player` ,1,50)
          FROM `hawk_playewadwds`;
      ```